# animate absolute div to fixed div

Tags: jquery, html, css, positioning

On my website i have a div with an absolute position in a parent div. What I want is when I click the div it has to enlarge and position in the middle of my browser.

What i tried is this:

```
$j("#mac").click(function(){
 $j('#mac').css({
        position: 'fixed'
    });

$j('#mac').animate({
    width: 923,
    height: 498,
    left: ($j(window).innerWidth() - 923)/2,
    top: ($j(window).innerHeight() - 498)/2
  }, 1000)});
```

It worked but  what happened is that the #mac first positioned to the left top corner of my screen and than animate to the center of my screen. This make sense because of the usage of position fixed. But when I dont use that position the div wont position at the center.

So i don't want to have te postioning at the left top corner of the screen but the div have to animate from his original position to the center of the screen.

Somebody know how to do this?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if you want to use an absolute position you must add the scroll position to bring it to the center of the viewport.

Comment: @SvenBieder thanks for your answer. Do you have a little example how to do this?

Comment: you do it in the same way like you have done it with the fixed position. but to left you add additionally window.pageXOffset and to top you add window.pageYOffset

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you change the CSS position to fixed, at the same time, find the current top and left positions of the DIV and set those as well. That should start the animation at the correct place.

```
var offset = $j('#mac').offset();

$j('#mac').css({
    position: 'fixed',
    top: offset.top,
    left: offset.left
});
```

Comment: John, One more question. When I trie to reduce the div to his orignal size and position the animation starts at the bottom of the screen. How can i set this properly?

Comment: I would try to keep the fixed position, then go back to where it was before. So right back to the `offset` that you started with. Then just switch it back to absolute positioning. Basically just remember where it was before and go right back to it before switching to absolute again.